# Error in event_data("plotly_hover")? ( r plotly, shiny)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

Within a Shiny app, I'm trying to link multiple plots. To do this, I need to be able to retrieve hover data with something like `event_data("plotly_hover")`. Although this has worked for me before, today for some reason I've been running into a problem I haven't been able to troubleshoot. When I hover over any plotly object and display the hover event data, this error is returned within the Shiny app:

`Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`

In the past, using `event_data(...)` on a plotly object has worked well for me so I'm left scratching my head about what may be going on. Here is some self-contained sample code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("singlePlot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("hoverData")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$singlePlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, color = I("red"), marker = list(color = "blue"))
    p
  })

  output$hoverData <- renderText(event_data("plotly_hover"))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In theory I should see something like this:

```
      curveNumber  pointNumber      x      y 
1               0            1      1      4
```

But I'm left with the error above. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because `renderText` doesn't know how to treat a `dataframe`, as the name suggests it renders text, nothing else that does not meet the "string" qualification will work probably. Wrapping it in as.character solves your issue too. `renderText( as.character(event_data("plotly_hover")))`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("singlePlot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("hoverData")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$singlePlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, color = I("red"), marker = list(color = "blue"))
    p
  })

  output$hoverData <- renderText( as.character(event_data("plotly_hover")))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I found out `renderPrint()` worked well, but I wasn't quite sure why. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: you're welcome, and renderPrint is the better way to go at it here yes. Enjoy the shiny experience! (I'm guessing you are relatively new to it?)

Comment: Exactly-- I'm still getting a hang of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay-- I found the solution... kind of silly, but using `renderPrint()` instead of `renderText()` works seamlessly. Whoops! Thanks.